# When did the phrase "draw into one's orbit" first appear?

Tags: history

My question is a bit more complicated than that, actually. Here's a quote from Vladimir Nabokov's "Lolita":

> "Whose cat has scratched poor you?" A full-blown fleshy handsome woman
>   of the repulsive type to which I was particularly attractive might ask
>   me at the "lodge," during a table d'hote dinner followed by dancing
>   promised to Lo. This was one of the reasons why I tried to keep as far
>   away from people as possible, while Lo, on the other hand, would do
>   her utmost to **draw** as many potential witnesses **into her orbit** as she
>   could.

Was it before or after "orbit" became a popular astronomical term? (I.e. before or after Kepler?)

Comment: "draw into orbit" suggests two things to me, circular motion (like a planet) and an attractive force (like gravity) so I'd go for post Kepler.

Comment: You want to know the first attested metaphorical use, where a person is compared to a celestial body with gravitational pull sufficient to attract people into an orbit around them? Or are you asking if **orbit** had a literal meaning that predated its astronomical one (other than eye-socket)?

Comment: @TimRomano: Neither, actually. I've been wondering whether it wasn't the former (person) that inspired the coinage of the latter (celestial body).

Comment: "Orbit" comes from the latin "orbis" that designates 1) any kind of circles 2) the course of events 3) circular surface like a disc 4) the world 5) things entering in the scope of another one, i.e. the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Orbit](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=orbit%20&searchmode=none): (Etymonline)

> - ***Astronomical sense first recorded 1690s*** in English; it was in classical Latin, revived in Gerard of Cremona's translation of Avicenna.

According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=into%20orbit%2Cinto%20my%20orbit%2Cinto%20his%20orbit%2C%20into%20her%20orbit%20&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinto%20orbit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinto%20my%20orbit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinto%20his%20orbit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinto%20her%20orbit%3B%2Cc0), the expression ***into orbit*** appears to be  quite recent, from the 50's.

> - ***Johannes Kepler ( December 27, 1571 – November 15, 1630)*** was a German mathematician,  astronomer, and astrologer.

Wikipedia

Comment: You used a starting date of 1900, which eliminated earlier attestations of "into her orbit"

Comment: @TimRomano -     Is that the reason for the downvote?  Earlier attestations of "into her orbit" do not appear to be relevant either : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=into+orbit%2Cinto+my+orbit%2Cinto+his+orbit%2Cinto+her+orbit&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinto%20orbit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinto%20my%20orbit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinto%20his%20orbit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinto%20her%20orbit%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Yes. If you wish to repair that oversight I'd remove the downvote, though now that we know the OP wanted to know if **orbit** had originally meant *a person's sway or influence* and was only later used in the astronomical sense, it might be moot, and you might just want to remove the ngram entirely along with the remark about Kepler, and I would remove the downvote in that case as well.

Comment: It is just ok like that, I just wanted to understand what is for you a valid reason for downvoting.

Comment: I'm upvoting this to compensate for the downvote. I hate bad manners.

Comment: @Ricky - thanks but I was not looking for that. If you clarify what you are asking I could fix my answer in that respect.

Comment: @Ricky: I don't think it's bad manners to use a downvote to critique an answer for its methodology. It can be bad manners to vote something down without offering a reason, leaving the poster wondering.  It's quite common on SE to remove downvotes when an answer is improved or otherwise fixed.

Comment: @TimRomano - the fact is that your "critique" does not appear to be a solid one. Earlier attestations of "in her orbit" as shown in the attached Ngram are not relevant, and quite rare. If you can provide solid evidence contrary to what I am saying, please do.

Comment: @TimRomano: Why can't critiques be offered without downvoting? Aren't we all grownups here? It's so damn petty.,

Comment: @Ricky - that a fair point, but up/down votes are exempt from any justification, it is just a question of personal attitude.

Comment: @Josh61: The OP's question was about **personal influence**, so I'm not sure why you included "into orbit" in your search. Was the bio blurb about Kepler intended as *lagniappe*?

Comment: @TimRomano    -,    I may have misunderstood the question, which appears to be unclear to you, too. Anyway what I wanted to show is that "orbit" is not a term that comes from Kepler (see Etymonline ) and that any expression which contains "into (my/her/his) orbit shows relevant evidence only after the 50's, probably with the space missions of those years. Ngram just shows that.

Comment: @Josh61: There are attestations from the 1860s.  20th century space missions don't explain the use. https://books.google.com/books?id=eeBMAAAAMAAJ&q=%22into+her+orbit%22&dq=%22into+her+orbit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0it_ZgqnJAhXE7SYKHUmyAxEQ6AEIOTAE

Comment: @Josh61: Exempt, aren't they? Hmm. It is my belief that people of passion, and language enthusiasts in particular, should stick together. Aggressive anti-intellectualism is on the march, you know. It used to be "education to the masses," but now it's "ignorance and entitlement to the philistines" - while we bicker. I'm only half-joking here.

Comment: @TimRomano - "orbit" referring to astronomy is from 1690, so no wonder that there are 19th reference to that. My point is that the expression took off only in recent decades, and I feel modern space missions have something to do with that. Your different respectable opinion may be expressed in an answer rather than here.